# Execute URL File in Sharepoint (Mime Type?)

Tags: web-application, hyperlink, shortcut

I have unblocked the ".URL" file extension in SharePoint that allows them to upload a link/shortcut, however SharePoint's strict `Browser File Handling` seemingly won't render the file - but requires you to download it:

[image]

Does anyone know the correct MIME Type I should use so that the URL files work without saving? The [FileXT site](http://filext.com/file-extension/URL) provides a list of the following:

- wwwserver/redirection
- application/internet-shortcut
- application/x-url
- message/external-body
- text/url
- text/x-url

I tried #2 as a test but it didn't work. None of these MIME Types appear to be defined in IIS either.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the links list in SharePoint instead?

[image]

> ## About links lists
>
> You can use links lists to post hyperlinks to Web pages of interest to your team. By default, creating a site creates a links list that appears on the home page of your site. To see all of the links in this default list, click the list title on the home page. You can also create additional links lists to organize your links.

Reference: [About links lists](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/about-links-lists-HA001161176.aspx)

Comment: These are links within a document library - e.g. to another folder.